# Unexpected Json when installing Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I'm not familiar with `npm` so I tried to download `Firebase CLI binary for Windows`.

When I ran the `.exe` it gives me the following error:

[image]

Any idea why it happens?

I ran it on Windows 10 Pro, 64bit.

Thank you